# Problem with UIActionSheet and iPad keyboard

Tags: ipad, ios

i have problem with UIACtionSheet and iPad keyboard , when try to show an UIActionSheet with `firstResponder` keyboard my sheet becomes like this :
[image]

what is the problem ?

Comment: In your example, it looks like theres no reason to show the keyboard, since theres nothing to type in. Could you provide some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a UIActionSheet, you dont really need to use `firstResponder` unless you have a textField or something else to type in.